# MySQL Master-Master replication performance

Tags: mysql, performance, replication

I have the following situation:
I have to set up a high-performance server-cluster with maximum availability with nginx and MySQL. The cluster consists of four web servers which are load ballanced with nginx+gluster which works just fine.

In addition there's another server with 2 SSDs in RAID1. On that server I intend to install 2 VMs each with 12GB of RAM where I set up the MySQL cluster with Master-Master replication.
But that only prevents the system to break down if the MySQL service breaks down on one of the VMs, not if the host system is offline.

To counter that I thought of adding 2 more nodes on other machines to the MySQL cluster as failover. Unfortunately I don't have more machines with SSDs.

Now my question: Would I have to expect performance issues because of the much slower hard drives on the failover machines? And if so, would these issues occur only when inserting data or also when calling pure select queries? 
Of course I'd set the loadballancer to prioritize the faster nodes.

Comment: you should refer this:(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html), ..(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html)

Comment: Thanks, but the first link is about Master-Slave replication and the second link is about cluster replication (with more than one cluster). What you meant was propably this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster.html, but there's nothing about performance issues and bottlenecks.